# Unable to resume if suspended for more than 20 minutes on a Dell Inspiron N5010

Tags: 11.04, ati, dell, suspend-resume, inspiron

I am using 11.04 64bit on Dell Inspiron N5010. I have this strange problem, if I leave my laptop suspended for more than 20 minutes(approx.) then it does not resume.

It works fine if I resume within or less than 20 minutes. I have 4GB ram and 8GB swap space, my system have ATI 5000 series graphics card and and I am using proprietary drivers installed via jockey.

Comment: Ditto, (not sure exactly 20 min) on pretty powerful PC, ignored it because OSs in general are hopeless at resuming.

Comment: It used to work fine for me till 10.10, although Hibernation still works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have solved this problem. The solution is to use tuxonice patched kernel. Its very simple, just follow these steps.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tuxonice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tuxonice-userui linux-generic-tuxonice linux-headers-generic-tuxonice
```

Restart your system. Thats it.